# I don't want my app to get uninstalled by user for a particular period of time

Tags: android, android-studio

is there any option in android studio to make an app so that user can not able to uninstall it for a particular period of time. For example if user granted permission of not uninstalling the app for one hour , so user can not uninstall this app for one hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this, unless the app is enrolled in Android Enterprise (which is their program to allow businesses to control fleets of hardware.  Using that you can install apps and prevent their uninstallation).  Otherwise no, there's no way an app can prevent the user from uninstalling itself.  That would basically make malware unremovable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent user to uninstall the app for particular period of time.
Thanks